# Solving $y''+4y=t^2$ by undetermined coefficients

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

$$y''+4y=t^2$$

I did:

$$y = at^2+bt+c\\y' = 2at+b\\y''=2a$$
Then:

$$y''+4y=t^2 = 2a+4at^2+4bt+4c = t^2\\t^2(4a)+t(4b)+1(4c) = t^2+0t+1\cdot0\implies\\a = \frac{1}{4}, b = 0, c = 0\implies \\y = \frac{1}{4}t^2$$

but [wolfram alpha gives](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%27%27%2B4y%27%3D%20t%5E2):

$$\frac{t^3}{12}-\frac{t^2}{16}+\frac{t}{32}$$

where did it came from? Specially $t^3$... I should only suppose a polynomail up to the 2nd degree.

update: [this is the righ](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%27%27%2B4y%3D%20t%5E2)t wolfram alpha answer

$$\frac{1}{4}t^2-\frac{1}{8}$$

where did the $-\frac{1}{8}$ came from?

Comment: It appears when you were substituting derivatives of $y$, you lost a $2a$ along the way.

Comment: You could also use a green's function for this by using $y(t)=\int_{z=0}^{\infty}G(t,z)f(z)dz$. Not the method you wanted, but just pointing it out.

Comment: @BrianYao you're right, I found it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where you went wrong is in the second line of your reasoning:  It should have read (based on your correct first line)
$$
t^2(4a) + t(4b) + 1(4c\color{red}{+2a}) = t^2(1) + t(0) + 1(0)
$$
From this, you can see that $c=-\frac12 a$ and $a=\frac14$ so one solution of the differential equation is 
$$y = \frac14 t^2 -\frac18 $$
The general solution is, of course,
$$
y = \frac14 t^2 -\frac18 + M\sin \left(\frac12 (t+\delta)  \right)
$$

Answer (score 1):

First realize that $(t^2)''=2$, hence let:
$$4x(t)=4y(t)-t^2+\frac{1}{2}$$

$$\Rightarrow x''(t)=y''(t)-\frac{1}{2}$$

The equation becomes:

$$x''(t)=-4x(t)$$

Note that this can be seen as a differential equations relating the position($x(t)$) and acceleration

($a(t)=x''(t)$) of an object in harmonic motion, the solution of which:
$$x(t)=Acos(2t + \varphi)$$
with constants $A,\varphi $

substitue back to get the answer

Answer (score 0):

The forcing function on the right side is of degree two, and you'll need to add two extra degrees - one for each derivative in the highest occurrence - to do this right. That is, you need to assume $y = ax^4 + bx^3 + cx^2 + dx + e$ to start.

Comment: A polynomial of degree 2 suffices for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

For
$y''+4y=t^2
$,
suppose
$y
= y(t)
=\sum_{k=0}^d a_k t^k
$
with
$a_d \ne 0$.

Then
$y'
=\sum_{k=1}^d k a_k t^{k-1}
=\sum_{k=0}^{d-1} (k+1) a_{k+1} t^{k}
$
and
$y''
=\sum_{k=1}^{d-1} k(k+1) a_{k+1} t^{k-1}
=\sum_{k=0}^{d-2} (k+1)(k+2) a_{k+2} t^{k}
$.

Adding,
and replacing the "$4$"
by "$c$" for generality,

$\begin{array}\\
y''+cy
&=\sum_{k=0}^{d-2} (k+1)(k+2) a_{k+2} t^{k}+c\sum_{k=0}^d a_k t^k\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{d-2} (k+1)(k+2) a_{k+2} t^{k}+c\sum_{k=0}^{d-2} a_k t^k
+ca_{d-1}t^{d-1}+ca_d t_d\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{d-2} ((k+1)(k+2) a_{k+2}+ca_k) t^k
+ca_{d-1}t^{d-1}+ca_d t^d\\
\end{array}
$

If this is $t^2$,
we must have
$d=2$
(or else there are terms
of degree higher than $2$)
and
$ca_2 = 1$,
so $a_2 = \frac1{c}$.

Similarly,
we must have
$a_1 = 0$.

That only leaves the
$k=0$ term in the summation
which gives us
$2a_2+ca_0 = 0$,
so
$a_0
=\frac{-2a_2}{c}
=\frac{-2}{c^2}
$.

Therefore
$y(t)
=\frac{t^2}{c}-\frac{2}{c^2}
$.

Check:

$y'(t)
=\frac{2t}{c}
$,
$y''(t)
=\frac{2}{c}
$,
so
$y''+cy
=\frac{2}{c}+c(\frac{t^2}{c}-\frac{2}{c^2})
=\frac{2}{c}+t^2-\frac{2}{c}
=t^2
$
as desired.

If $c=4$,
the solution is
$\frac{t^2}{4}-\frac{2}{16}
=\frac{t^2}{4}-\frac{1}{8}
$.